# Java - multithreading increment

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, synchronization

I have the following class in my application

```
public class InsertErrorLinesHandler {

    private int currentCount;

    public void insertErrorLine() {
        //do something...
        currentCount++;
    }
}
```

And I have multiple threads that are using the same instance of `InsertErrorLinesHandler`, particulary calling insertErrorLine method. After all these threads are stopped, I get the `currentCount` from this instance.

The question is - how to rewrite this class to be sure that there won't be any concurrency problems? What I want is to be sure, that `currentCount` value will be the count of method callings from threads. Should I use static method and static variable? Make method synchronize? Make variable volatile?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suggest using an [AtomicInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html), which has a thread-safe increment method

Comment: Brian Goetz's book "Java Concurrency in Practice" specifically addresses the issue of keeping a counter that's accessible from multiple threads. His solution is to use an `AtomicLong`. Simple, and effective.

Answer (score 3):

Simple fix, make the method call synchronized:

```
public class InsertErrorLinesHandler {

    private int currentCount;

    public void synchronized insertErrorLine() {
        //do something...
        currentCount++;
    }
}
```

Comment: That is how I'd like to do it, but there was doubts, maybe there's a better way...

Comment: The best way is usually the simplest. Other methods will involve having a static object which is used to synchronize the increment operation, importing several classes, or even rewriting the class. Choose wisely

Comment: Simple, yes; but very inefficient if `//do something...` takes significant time and does not impact other threads.  Less simple, but more optimal would be to wrap a `synchronized` block around the `currentCount++` statement.

Comment: It amuses me to see that your simple fix contains a huge bug. Without marking the field as volatile, other threads may fail to see a change. Synchronized alone does not make things safe for multithreading.

Comment: @NicoVanBelle, I see your point about making it volatile, but is that implying that after a thread enters the synchronized block and does `currentCount++`, there is a chance that the actual value of `currentCount` would not have been written to memory?

Comment: You may ignore my previous comment as I indeed thought a modification would be written to the CPU cache. I always remembered visibility was obtained by using `volatile` explicitly but the usage of `synchronized` alone provides the same visibility!

Comment: @NicoVanBelle, you raised an interesting point, so I'm still going to experiment a bit with this and see if I can potentially reproduce the bug you described. I will update this thread with my results

Answer (score 2):

Use [AtomicInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) or use [LongAdder](https://minddotout.wordpress.com/2013/05/11/java-8-concurrency-longadder/) when number of threads are more for better performance.

Here is the example on how to use AtomicInteger,

```
public class InsertErrorLinesHandler {
   AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();

   public void insertErrorLine() {
       counter.incrementAndGet();
   }

   public int get() {
       return counter.get();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

So far, nobody's addressed this part of your question:

> Should I use static...?

The choice of whether or not to use `static` is completely independent of the choice of whether to use `synchronized` or `AtomicInteger` or not.  The answer depends on what you want to count.

A `static` field in Java is what some other languages call a *global* variable:  There is only one of it for the entire program.  A non-static field (a.k.a., an *instance variable*) exists in multiple copies---one for each instance of the class to which it belongs.

How many instances of the `InsertErrorLineHandler` class does your program create?  If more than one, then do you want each instance to have its own `counter`, or do you want all of them to share the same `counter`?  Declaring the field `static` means that they will all share the same, and leaving out the `static` keyword means that each instance will have its own counter.

If your program only ever creates one `InsertErrorLineHandler` instance (i.e., if you are using it as a *singleton* class) then you should not use `static`.  Making fields `static` or not static won't change the behavior of a singleton, but using `static` in a singleton would be bad style.

Comment: Only one instance of  `InsertErrorLineHandler`. So I think it was right that I didn't use `static`